# Preventing xlsread from importing formatted but empty cells

Tags: excel, matlab

I'm reading an Excel file via xlsread and creating a cell array of the raw values: `[~, ~, raw_values] = xlsread(filename,'sheet1');`

Some cells in the sheet previously contained values, which have since been deleted. However, the dimensions of `raw_values` still cover the range where these values used to be. Thus, `raw_values` contains a lot of trailing columns which contain nothing but NaNs.

I can't see a difference in Excel between the cells which previously contained values and those that didn't. The formatting of both is 'Standard'. However, if I use the Format Painter to copy the formatting from untainted cells to the affected ones, the column no longer get's imported by xlsread.

How can I prevent these trailing NaN columns (and rows) from being created by xlsread or delete them in an elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: `xlsread` is not recommended starting in *R2019a* (see [doc](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html)).
Hence if you dont need the backwards compatibility I'd use `readtable` instead.

With readtable you can specify a bunch of import options for example how to handle missing values or specify the range to be imported [cf. spreadheet import options](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.spreadsheet.spreadsheetimportoptions.html).

In case you still need to delete nan values an elegant approach would be to build a logical array with `isnan()` and then use this array to delete the corresponding rows/columns.
Example:

```
AA = [magic(5) nan(5,1)];
disp(AA)
idxNanCol = all(isnan(AA));
AA(:, idxNanCol) = [];
disp(AA)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should return a matrix indicating which position of raw_values are not NaNs

```
index=~cellfun(@isnan,raw_values)
```

If you want to keep only the non NaN values:

```
raw_values(index)
```